# IntelliJ can't detect main.scala.html indexation

Tags: html, scala, intellij-idea

I searched a lot but i can't find any help, some people can handle it, some say play 2.x just works on ultimate version of intellij, is there a way to get rid of the red in my Play! templates on IntelliJ?

for example i get a "Unexpected tokens" error on `<!DOCTYPE Html>`

[image]

also a "Tag start is not closed" on
`<divid="mydiv"style="backgroundimage:url('@routes.Assets.at("images/myImage.jpg")')">`

is there something i can do?

Comment: Is it in a play project?

Comment: yes it is, i imported a Play! project to intellij.

Comment: Well after a long time trying and retrying things, uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ Comunity version i downloaded the trial of the Ultimate version and everything worked like a charm, i suppose Play! do not work well on community version i hope i'm wrong, i'll left it in comment over an answer maybe there is a way to make it work.

Comment: same here. I suspect that is JetBrains' trick to get the money out of your pocket. I did in eclipse http://localhost:9000/@documentation/IDE  everything is fine. try it.

Answer (score 0):

The icon on your editor tab should have the three orange Scala bars overlaid across the green document, and it doesn't, so for some reason Intellij is not recognizing your document as a template.  Is your html file in your source path?

If that's not the problem, I'd try creating a new Play 2.x project and see what the behavior is there.  Assuming it works correctly, start looking for what's different.  If you have no luck, check the [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL?q=play%20framework%20template).  I don't see anything germane there, though.

Comment: well, i downloaded the "Ultimate" version trial and now everything works ok, i really think is something wrong with the community version.

Comment: @cajuuh - It's possible, though I'd expect someone would report it.  Speaking of which... why don't you?  Be sure to include detailed version info for both plugin and IJ.